# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sbt/PlayInternalKeys

Tags: java, scala, sbt, noclassdeffounderror, playframework-2.1

When I (try to) start Play, I see this:

```
[info] Loading global plugins from /home/paul/.sbt/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /home/my-project/project
[error] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sbt/PlayInternalKeys
[error] Use 'last' for the full log
```

I am loading a custom sbt plugin.

What does that error mean?

(FYI, I'm assuming that last line says I can run `play last`. I can't. It gives the same error.)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I found that my Play project wasn't pulling in the SNAPSHOT versions I was publishing to my local repo for the sbt plugin.

I had to increment the version numbers myself. When I did that, I did not see this error anymore. (I did continue to have to update the version when I changed the plugin.)